# Отличие try...catch от throws

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

В чем принципиальное отличие

```
try {

}catch(Exception e){

}
```

от `throws`

Comment: `throw` кидает исключение, `try...catch` - ловит.

Comment: `throws` указывает, что метод выбрасывает исключение, `try .. catch` его ловит и обрабатывает.

Comment: Истину глаголют. throw - бросать, try - пытаться, catch - ловить.Один типа такой бросает, другой пытается поймать. (на самом деле пытается несколько другое сделать, но тем не менее ловит иногда)

Comment: @Sergey забавно, но `throw` и `throws` это **разные** вещи.

Comment: И правда throws, не обратил внимания старый дурак. throws типа предупреждает, что кто-то что-то может кинуть, и тогда хочешь, не хочешь, а ловить придётся (или перекинуть в следующего).

Comment: @Sergey А если метод со `throws` выбросит другое исключение, не указанное после него, напиример `throws NullPointerException` выбросит `StackOverflow`?

Comment: @Herrgott, а он не может :)

Comment: `NullPointerException` - непроверяемое исключение. `throws` описывает проверяемые исключения.

Comment: @Nofate Почему, если я напишу `throws NullPointerException`

Comment: `throws` может описывать любые исключения, но компилятор будет выдавать ошибку только на необработанные проверяемые. В рантайме разницы между checked и unchecked исключениями вообще нет.

Comment: в java исключения разделаются на несколько классов. Есть так называемые checked и uncheked исключения. В throws можно перечислить checked. Предполагается, что метод знает какие ошибки совершает - они cheked. uncheked - нежданчик разной степени. О них невозможно предупредить

Answer (score 9, accepted):

При обработке исключений всегда есть 2 варианта : либо пробрасываем выше (т.е. добавляем throws к сигнатуре метода), либо обрабатываем "на месте", используя try-catch

Comment: Но я все равно не могу понять, почему нельзя использовать всегда try...catch... И смысл этого `throws`

Comment: не всегда можно обработать исключение в тот методе, где оно было брошено.

Comment: @Herrgott не всегда можно обработать исключение там, где оно было брошено. Иначе механизм исключений вообще был бы не нужен.

Comment: @Herrgott, смысл _throws_ в том, что по сигнатуре метода сразу видно какие исключения в нем могут быть, соответственно не надо отлавливать глобальным try...catch базовое исключение, а можно отловить только конкретное нужное

Comment: @Nofate Вроде начинаю вникать помаленьку

Comment: Дело не в том, что не возможно обработать, а в том, что сам метод бросает исключение. throws - это предупреждение какие исключения стоит ждать от данного метода. Это можно даже трактовать как альтернативный результат.

Comment: @Sergey И получается можно указать несколько типов исключений для одного метода, вроде как предупреждение перед использованием?

Comment: вы можете использовать try-catch, а можете throws. Все зависит от тех целей, которые вы преследуете. Может вы хотите специально пробросить исключение(throws), чтобы обработать его где-то выше. Например у вас есть 3-5-10 методов, которые throws исключение. В итоге вы можете обработать их всех разом в том месте, где эти методы вызываются.

Comment: @Herrgott, да. И другой метод, который вызовет метод с `throws` должен будет либо явно ловить исключения, либо прокидывать дальше через `throws`.

Comment: @Nofate Ну вроде понял все, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос в том где вам удобнее произвести эту обработку. `try-catch` как раз для этой обработки и служит, но не всегда удобно обрабатывать исключение в том месте где оно бросается.

`throws` позволяет не обрабатывать исключение в том месте которое его вызывает, а переложить эту работу на то место в коде где вы будете  вызывать метод через сигнатуру которого вы это исключение пробросили.

На пример:

```
a() {
    try {
    // какой-то код который может выбросить исключение
    } catch (Exception e) { ... }
}

b() {
    a(); // и тут не каких исключений не надо ловить вы его уже поймали
}
```

Или если вы не хотите ловить в методе `a()` то вы можете сделать так:

```
a() throws Exception {
    // какой-то код который может выбросить исключение но мы его пробрасываем

}

b() {
    try {
        a();// и ловим тут потому что в методе a() мы это делать не стали
    } catch (Exception e) { ... }
}
```

Во втором примере мы могли бы еще дальше его пробрасывать написав `b() throws Exception` вплоть до метода `main` и вообще его не ловить, но так лучше не делать.

То есть исключение это места где `java` говорит: тут может быть проблема, а вы должны что-то ответить, на пример: да здесь и обработаем и пишите `try-catch` или нет здесь не хочу давай потом и с помощью `throws` откладываете решение.

Comment: А если в коде используется чисто `throws`, то это означает, что метод просто выбрасывает исключение без обработки?

Comment: @invzbl3 да верно, и в том методе который будет его использовать придется обрабатывать исключение либо пробрасывать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже возник подобный вопрос, решил потестить. Вот пример кода:

```
    public class Exeptions {

    static void throwOne() {   // не указан throws 
        System.out.println("В теле метода throwOne()");
        throw new NullPointerException("нулпоинтер");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throwOne();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Возвращение в main");
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
    В теле метода throwOne()
java.lang.NullPointerException: нулпоинтер
    at Exeptions.throwOne(Exeptions.java:6)
    at Exeptions.main(Exeptions.java:16)
Возвращение в main
```

Как видно все прекрасно скомпилировалось, но если выкинуть любое проверяемое исключение и не прописать `throws` - компилятор выдаст ошибку.

Итог: "обязательно указывать `throws` для всех исключений, кроме тех, которые относятся к классам Error и RuntimeException или любым их подклассам.
Все остальные исключения, которые может сгенерировать метод, должны быть
объявлены в операторе throws. Если этого не сделать, то во время компиляции
возникнет ошибка." - Шилдт.